# JSON.Net Always returns {}

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, json.net

Foo

```
Public Class Foo
    Private fooz As Object
    Private alao As ArrayList

    Public Sub New(ByVal pfooz)
        Me.fooz = New Object
        Me.alao = New ArrayList()

        Me.alao.Add(1)
        Me.alao.Add(2)
        Me.alao.Add(3)
        Me.alao.Add(4)
        Me.alao.Add(5)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Bar

```
Public Class Bar
    Private baz As Integer
    Private bar As String
    Private foo As Foo

    Public Sub New(ByVal pbaz, ByVal pbar, ByVal pfoo)
        Me.baz = pbaz
        Me.bar = pbar
        Me.foo = pfoo
    End Sub
End Class
```

My Form

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim foo As Foo = New Foo(New Object)
        Dim bar As Bar = New Bar(1, "FOOOOOOOOOOOOO, bar?", foo)
        Dim fooString As String
        Dim barString As String

        fooString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo)
        barString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bar)

        MsgBox(fooString)
        MsgBox(barString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I always get {} as answer. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these classes have any `Public` properties or fields. If you want to represent your fields as values that should be present in a JSON string, make them public. Otherwise, as far as the serializer is concerned, you're giving it objects with no interesting values on them.

Comment: Thank you! Working! Is it possible to JSON.NET uses get methods instead of public members?

Comment: @thom: That's what Properties are for. If you create a public property with a public `Get` method on it, JSON.NET will pick that up. Don't try to use `getXxx()`-style methods like in Java. Also note that additional changes will be necessary if you want to *de*serialize your object.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think you can get around that semantic by adding the [JsonProperty Attribute](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to the members you want serialized regardless of its access modifier. You may have to designate the class as a [JsonObject](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm) for this to work properly.  I'm honestly not sure off the top of my head.  Some people are philosophically opposed to getters/setters as part of OO methodology, so this can be useful.